# How to run Jython with __debug__ False

Tags: optimization, jython

Seems like a silly question, but I'm scratching my head about this.

Jython 2.7.0 "final release", platform W7

I simply want to run my app so that __debug__ is False and so that assert statements are skipped.

I tried going
`jython -O my_app.py` 
and it said

> Unknown option: O

... did some googling but to no avail...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

anyone seeking the answer

https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/jython-essentials/9781449397364/apds02.html

> Major Design Differences
>
> Debug and optimization
>
> Jython does not currently recognize the CPython command-line switch -O, which removes assert statements and other debug
>   information. In Jython, the __debug__ global value, which controls
>   this behavior, is always set to 1 and is not writable.

... so (for the moment) you have to implement your own (switch-offable) assert-style mechanisms.  Potentially somewhat problematic, because even having a boolean "is_production_run" is going to take time to evaluate, though for all I know this might just be one machine instruction.

I wonder if the Jython high command have got any plans to implement this feature one day?  I can't imagine it would be that complicated...